# PHP cURL No Error but not working

Tags: php, curl

I've been banging my head on this for a while now and I'm sorta fed up. I'm not a PHP programmer so I might be missing something that is not immediately obvious to my Python infused brain.

So here's the context. I need to write a script to login automatically into a web interface and run a search, and well, absolutely everything I've tried to do seems to fail miserably.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
echo 'start';
// INIT CURL
$ch = curl_init();

// SET URL FOR THE POST FORM LOGIN
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://W0110DcIpsOcsRpt02/si_ocs_gui/login.php');

// ENABLE HTTP POST
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

// SET POST PARAMETERS : FORM VALUES FOR EACH FIELD

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'username=*****&password=*****&btnSubmit=Login');

// IMITATE CLASSIC BROWSER'S BEHAVIOUR : HANDLE COOKIES
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/var/tmp/cookie.txt');

# Setting CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER variable to 1 will force cURL
# not to print out the results of its query.
# Instead, it will return the results as a string return value
# from curl_exec() instead of the usual true/false.
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);

// EXECUTE 1st REQUEST (FORM LOGIN)
$store = curl_exec ($ch);

if($store == False){
        echo " store false ";
        echo curl_error($ch);
} else {
        echo " store true ";
        echo $store;
}

// SET FILE TO DOWNLOAD
echo ' second_request ';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://W0110DcIpsOcsRpt02/si_ocs_gui/FWOCS1_BL_SUBSCRIBERS_list.php');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
#curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'value_ACCESS_NO_4=15142351150');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'q=\(SUBSCRIBER_ID~equals~1545303\)');
// EXECUTE 2nd REQUEST (FILE DOWNLOAD)
if(!$store == False){
        $content = curl_exec ($ch);
        echo $content;
}
// CLOSE CURL

curl_close($ch);

echo ' done';
?>
```

The behaviour of this is as follows. I run the script, and it fails at the first cURL request (the login) and returns no errors. I have modified this line here:

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'username=*****&password=*****&btnSubmit=Login');
```

by removing the `btnSubmit=Login` part and I get the login page displayed with the filled in username and password fields. I can press the login button and it will work. However, it seems that my lack of web development is biting me here and I have no idea how that button works. So, here's the code inspected with firebug:

```
<a class="rnr-button main" href="#" onclick="document.forms[0].submit();return false;">Submit</a>
```

I also went directly in the PHP code on the web server and found the button corresponding to it:

```
if ((@$_POST["btnSubmit"] == "Login" || $adSubmit) && $logacc)
```

Hence why I was trying the `btnSubmit=Login`.

So my question is pretty simple: what am I doing wrong and how can I get the results I need?

Comment: Make sure error reporting is on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php

Comment: So you want to automagically submit the form? Writing a small API with basic authentication would be a better solution to your problem. Bypasses the form altogether. But to address the issue at hand, there needs to be something on the form that will submit the login info that you give it.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same problem and find the solution for it.

Code

CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => false

Use this to solve your problem.